# Matching Trimble Data Dictionary File (.DDF) to File Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, trimble

I'm implementing a new database model in our company's GIS (Utility). We collect field data with Trimble units. I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a Trimble data dictionary that matches the schema (fields and domains) of the database.

I want to easily be able to load data from the field into GIS with out much editing or modification.

Is there a way to export the schema from Esri's file geodatabase to a Trimble .ddf file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have or get the ArcGIS add-in from Trimble called "Trimble Positions Desktop" you can create a .ddf file based on the feature classes you have in the mxd you base the project on.